# Using Angular's ActivatedRoute outside component / without injection

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a helper to get some URL param for me, using ActivatedRoute.

The normal way, injecting ActivatedRoute on component, is working fine, like this:

```js
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private api: MyApiService
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.api.getData(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id") || "").subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
    }, (error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
    })
}
```

Now I want to create a helper file with some `getIdFromUrl()` function that returns the ID string or an empty string, this way:

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

export function getIdFromUrl(): string
{
    var route = new ActivatedRoute();
    var id = route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    return id !== null ? id : "";
}
```

But can't make this to work and can't figure out why.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 this works, but I still need to inject ActivatedRoute on my component's constructor, to pass it as parameter to the getIdFromUrl... Do you know if there's another way that I don't need to inject it on component?

Answer (score 0):

Outlets have their own ActivatedRoute instance so you won't be able to get it from elsewhere as if it were a singleton.

However with Router it should be possible to do something like this. Here I've done a quick example with a service that can return a param retrieved from the url on one component and one that uses ActivatedRoute.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-juypes?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Would a similar service work for you or do you not want to inject a service either?

```
@Injectable()
export class GetParamFromRouteService {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  getIdFromRoute(): string {
    return this.router.routerState.snapshot.root.children[0].params['id'] || '';
  }
}
```